# What is the average duration between the 1st trip and the 2nd trip of customers? Note: Consider only the customers who have done 2 or more trips

Tags: sql, python-3.x

A bike rider company wants to know the average time duration between 1st trip and 2nd trip of every rider as they have trip_id,customer_id,timestamp,time_durtion_of_trip, distance_travel column details available.

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table calc(customer_id str, timestamp int);

insert into calc values("B", 28);
insert into calc values("A", 25);
insert into calc values("C", 22);
insert into calc values("A", 19);
insert into calc values("B", 29);
insert into calc values("C", 25);
insert into calc values("A", 28);
insert into calc values("B", 25);

--x =customer_id, y=timestamp
select x,(y-s) as new from
(SELECT x, y,LEAD(y, 1) OVER ( partition by x) AS FROM 
(select x,y,r from(SELECT 
 x,y,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
 PARTITION BY x

) as r
FROM 
calc ) t
where t.r<=2)) where s is  not null

/* 
Output:
A|6
B|-1
C|-3
*/
#Python Implementation
import datetime as dt
#a=is_one_more_cust[is_one_more_cust['customer_id']=="CUST_001"].groupby('customer_id').head(2) 
[["customer_id","timestamp"]]
a=is_one_more_cust.groupby('customer_id').head(2)[["customer_id","timestamp"]]
a["t2"]=a.groupby(['customer_id'])['timestamp'].shift(-1)
b=a.query('t2 != "NaT"')
def fun(b):
   if b["t2"] >= b["timestamp"]:
      return b["t2"]-b["timestamp"]
   else:
      return b["timestamp"]-b["t2"]
b["Duration"]=b.apply(lambda b : fun(b), axis=1)
print(b.dtypes) #timedelta64[ns]
c=b["Duration"].mean()
d =pd.to_timedelta(c)
print(d)
```